# Передача logging из дочернего окна в главное PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, логирование

У меня есть главное окно, в котором реализована запись логов. Из этого окна можно открыть дочернее и нужно из дочернего передавать логи тоже в первое окно в тот же текстбокс.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime, QTimer
import logging
from lr1 import lr1Window
from mainUI import Ui_MainWindow


class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = parent.ui.plainTextEdit
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()

        self.logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        self.logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s (%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) %('
                                                  'levelname)s:%(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.logTextBox)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui.action_open.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.ui.action_DIS_lab1.triggered.connect(self.open_lr1)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.start()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerUI)

    def timerUI(self):
        self.datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.ui.statusbar.showMessage(self.datetime.toString('dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm:ss'))

    def openFile(self):
        try:
            file_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter='*.txt')[0]
            file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf8")
            data = file.read()
            self.ui.plainTextEdit.append(data)
        except OSError as e:
            logging.debug(e)

    def open_lr1(self):
        self.lr1 = lr1Window(self.logTextBox)
        self.lr1.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main1 = MainWindow()
    main1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

в **lr1.py** нужно, как я понимаю, верно наследовать класс `QTextEditLogger`, никак не могу справиться с этим. Вызвать исключение там может только нажатие на кнопку "Считать!", если оставить поля Фамилии и Имени пустыми.

```
# lr1.py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from lr1UI import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class lr1Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, logTextBox):
        super(lr1Window, self).__init__()
        self.surname = ''
        self.name = ''
        self.surname_unicode = []
        self.name_unicode = []
        self.tail = ''
        self.result_unicode = []
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        self.logTextBox = logTextBox

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui.pushButton_calculate.clicked.connect(self.calculation)

    def checkInput(self):
        if self.surname == '' and self.name == '':
            raise ValueError('Surname`s and name`s forms are empty', 0)

    def calculation(self):
        try:
            self.surname = self.ui.surname_inp.text()
            self.name = self.ui.name_inp.text()
            self.checkInput()
            self.surname_unicode = [ord(n) for n in self.surname]
            self.name_unicode = [ord(n) for n in self.name]
            if len(self.name_unicode) < len(self.surname_unicode):
                self.result_unicode = [self.surname_unicode[i] ^ self.name_unicode[i] for i in
                                       range(len(self.name_unicode))]
                self.tail = self.surname[len(self.name_unicode):]
            elif len(self.name_unicode) > len(self.surname_unicode):
                self.result_unicode = [self.surname_unicode[i] ^ self.name_unicode[i] for i in
                                       range(len(self.surname_unicode))]
                self.tail = self.name[len(self.surname_unicode):]
            else:
                self.result_unicode = [self.surname_unicode[i] ^ self.name_unicode[i] for i in
                                       range(len(self.surname_unicode))]

            self.setSurname()
            self.setName()
            self.setTail()
            self.setResultUni()
            self.setResult(' '.join(map(chr, self.result_unicode)))

        except ValueError as e:
            self.logging(e)

    def setSurname(self):
        self.ui.unisurname_output.setText(' '.join(map(str, self.surname_unicode)))
        self.ui.splitter.adjustSize()

    def setName(self):
        self.ui.uniname_output.setText(' '.join(map(str, self.name_unicode)))
        self.ui.splitter_2.adjustSize()

    def setTail(self):
        self.ui.tail_output.setText(self.tail)
        self.ui.splitter_3.adjustSize()

    def setResultUni(self):
        self.ui.uniresult_output.setText(' '.join(map(str, self.result_unicode)))
        self.ui.splitter_4.adjustSize()

    def setResult(self, text, iswarning=False):
        self.ui.result_output.setText(text)
        if iswarning == True:
            self.ui.result_output.setStyleSheet('color: red;')
        self.ui.splitter_5.adjustSize()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main1 = lr1Window()
    main1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

То что есть сейчас, при запуске через дебагер, говорит, что во время обработки моего исключения происходит другое исключение:

```
'lr1Window' object has no attribute 'logging'
```

Чтобы все это запустилось нужные еще файлы с UI, [все лежит здесь](https://github.com/vikanoshina/-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я не проверял логику вашего кода, а исправил только пару ошибок, которые получил при запуске вашего примера. Проверьте:

**q1197933.py**

```
import sys
import logging
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from lr1UI import Ui_MainWindow
###
from mainUI import Ui_MainWindow as Main_Ui_MainWindow        # + as Main_Ui_MainWindow

#from lr1 import lr1Window
class lr1Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, logTextBox):
        super(lr1Window, self).__init__()
        self.surname = ''
        self.name = ''
        self.surname_unicode = []
        self.name_unicode = []
        self.tail = ''
        self.result_unicode = []
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        self.logTextBox = logTextBox

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui.pushButton_calculate.clicked.connect(self.calculation)

    def checkInput(self):
        if self.surname == '' and self.name == '':
            raise ValueError('Surname`s and name`s forms are empty', 0)

    def calculation(self):
        try:
            self.surname = self.ui.surname_inp.text()
            self.name = self.ui.name_inp.text()
            self.checkInput()
            self.surname_unicode = [ord(n) for n in self.surname]
            self.name_unicode = [ord(n) for n in self.name]
            if len(self.name_unicode) < len(self.surname_unicode):
                self.result_unicode = [self.surname_unicode[i] ^ self.name_unicode[i] for i in
                                       range(len(self.name_unicode))]
                self.tail = self.surname[len(self.name_unicode):]
            elif len(self.name_unicode) > len(self.surname_unicode):
                self.result_unicode = [self.surname_unicode[i] ^ self.name_unicode[i] for i in
                                       range(len(self.surname_unicode))]
                self.tail = self.name[len(self.surname_unicode):]
            else:
                self.result_unicode = [self.surname_unicode[i] ^ self.name_unicode[i] for i in
                                       range(len(self.surname_unicode))]

            self.setSurname()
            self.setName()
            self.setTail()
            self.setResultUni()
            self.setResult(' '.join(map(chr, self.result_unicode)))

        except ValueError as e:
###      
#            self.logging(e)                                            # ---
            logging.debug(e)                                            # +++

    def setSurname(self):
        self.ui.unisurname_output.setText(' '.join(map(str, self.surname_unicode)))
        self.ui.splitter.adjustSize()

    def setName(self):
        self.ui.uniname_output.setText(' '.join(map(str, self.name_unicode)))
        self.ui.splitter_2.adjustSize()

    def setTail(self):
        self.ui.tail_output.setText(self.tail)
        self.ui.splitter_3.adjustSize()

    def setResultUni(self):
        self.ui.uniresult_output.setText(' '.join(map(str, self.result_unicode)))
        self.ui.splitter_4.adjustSize()

    def setResult(self, text, iswarning=False):
        self.ui.result_output.setText(text)
        if iswarning == True:
            self.ui.result_output.setStyleSheet('color: red;')
        self.ui.splitter_5.adjustSize()
        

class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = parent.ui.plainTextEdit
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
###
        self.ui = Main_Ui_MainWindow()                # - Ui_MainWindow(), Main_Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()

        self.logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        self.logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s (%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) %('
                                                  'levelname)s:%(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.logTextBox)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui.action_open.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
        self.ui.action_DIS_lab1.triggered.connect(self.open_lr1)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.start()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerUI)

    def timerUI(self):
        self.datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.ui.statusbar.showMessage(self.datetime.toString('dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm:ss'))

    def openFile(self):
        try:
            file_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(filter='*.txt')[0]
            file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf8")
            data = file.read()
###
            self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(data)          # - append, + appendPlainText
        except OSError as e:
            logging.debug(e)

    def open_lr1(self):
        self.lr1 = lr1Window(self.logTextBox)
        self.lr1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main1 = MainWindow()
    main1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Только скажите, зачем менять Ui_MainWindow на Main_Ui_MainWindow

Comment: @a_vikt Потому что я собрал ваш `main.py` и `lr1.py` в один модуль, 
а оба модуля загружают формы из класса `Ui_MainWindow` и чтобы не было путанице сделал так: 
`from lr1UI import Ui_MainWindow` и 
`from mainUI import Ui_MainWindow as Main_Ui_MainWindow` 
Если вы будите делать как у вас (отдельные модули), оставьте как есть у вас. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour